# Internet connection lost

Tags: networking, windows-8.1

I have a problem with my internet connection. Sometimes, suddenly, the internet connection is lost for a few seconds (often four or five, but sometimes up to 30 seconds).

When I test the connection with

```
ping google.nl -n 100
```

sometimes it pings successfully 100 times to a Google server, but sometimes it states

> Ping request could not find host google.nl. Please check the name and try again.

It happens with both wifi and ethernet connection. Sometimes it also happens while loading a website; often I see above the Super User website *Super User requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load*.

Interestingly, when I try to connect (through the browser or pinging) to the resolved IP address of, for example, a Google server (in my case 74.125.136.94), it *always* works.

Remarkably, as far as I can remember, it is happening since I upgraded to Windows 8.1.

What can be the problem, and, more importantly, how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you check your network adapter power settings to see if the devices are being allowed to be turned off to save power.

Comment: @BigChris Crap, it seems to work. But why was my network device being turned off while the battery was charging *and* browsing the internet?

Comment: Is not whether the computer is charging, it's when the computer sees the device isn't being used for anything of consequence so it puts it into a particular state that effectively turns it off.

Comment: Crap, it's not the problem, I see. It was all good until now... Does it have something to do with DNS maybe?

Comment: If Internet browsing works then I'd rule out DNS. Can you ping your default gateway the 100 times and see if you get anything fail.

Comment: Pinging to my default gateway (which is 192.168.1.1) always works. Notice that I updated the question based on new observations.

Comment: The "blocked or failed to load" is concerning... you connect to google.nl - does the country have any firewall? How reliable is your ISP? Do you connect via any proxy?

Comment: @BigChris Super User suggested [this discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14752/discussion-between-mc-emperor-and-big-chris) to be moved to chat. I did.